# SQL numbers without decimals issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very odd situation in a database table.

I have a table with lots of columns, and one column TOTAL is defined as number (18,2) and an external procedure is doing insert of Invoices into it.

The problem is in some cases instead of 225.45 in column TOTAL, I'm getting the value 22545.
This happened randomly without any rules, for example I have 3000 inputs and only 3 lines showing values without decimal places.

Comment: Presumably the inputs don't have decimal places.  Also, is the value incorrect or are you just missing `.00`.  If the latter, then it is simply a display issue.

Comment: are you sure that when you got 22545 it is not really that ? a number with precision 18 and scale 2 is advisory, it means that you can insert numbers without decimals, and with decimals with scale up to 2. So if you have 22545 it means that the input was 22545.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure that this is not 22545, It should be 225.45 cos that value have been got from other table within is that value with decimal. I have also tried to define variable only as NUMBER